# UI update in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

My doubt is regarding the UI update in objective-C. For example let's consider this piece of code

```
 myButton.hidden= YES;
```

The documentation says that the button is not immediately hidden, but it will be done in the next run loop. How long it will take before it is actually hidden. Can it be considered instantaneous for practical purposes ?
I am asking this question because I need to hide a button when a certain process is 70% complete.

```
// on main thread

    if (completionPercentage == 70)
    {
     myButton.hidden= YES;
    // some other stuff
    }
```

but maybe for few milliseconds the button remains visible after the process is 70% complete and if it is tapped in that duration the app crashes.

**EDIT :**
I am updating regarding the two processes and the functionality of cancel button.

Process1 is running on a `NSThread`. The function of myButton is to cancel the thread that is running Process1. When Process1 is complete 70% then I `dispatch_async`on `HIGH_PRIORITY_QUEUE`another process that uses data from Process1. Lets call it Process2. Hence Process1 cannot be cancelled once Process2 is started. 
So in the above mentioned `If`block I hide `myButton`once Process1 is 70% complete. But it does not become hidden immediately hence the question.  Hope I have made it clear.

Comment: Have you tried going myButton.enabled = NO; or myButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO; before hiding it?

Comment: @Zhang I have not tried but I suspect the behavior will be same for the  enabled property as well. Even they will take effect in the next run loop.

Comment: try this in dispatch_async block.

Comment: What gets executed when you tap that button? Does the button tapped method depend on some data being processed ? Finding it odd that tapping on a button that isn't hooked to anything would cause a crash. Perhaps you could put a check in your button tapped method that completionPercentage >= 70 before executing it's intended code?

Comment: Append crash log please.

Comment: @Zhang Please have a look at the update.

Comment: Would you accept hiding the button at around 60% instead of 70%, so you basically hide the button well before process 2 started. That way, when process 2 starts at 70%, the button is already hidden. Does the app crash if you press cancel button even before 70% is reached? say at 30% you press the cancel button, does that crash the app?

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [mButton setHidden:YES];
});
```

It should be done as async

Comment: But the If statement is already on main_queue. Will it help dispatching  on main queue from inside a main_queue. I hope it will only delay the execution since it is being put as a separate block. The delay will be negligible however.